# pool = new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), IPADDRESS) is not working

Tags: redis, connection-pooling, remote-access, remote-server, jedis

My question is pretty explanatory, I'm not able to access a remote jedis server using the above statement.Here is a bit detail abt the code:

static JedisPool pool;
private Jedis jedis;

static {
    pool = new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), "A.B.C.D"); // A.B.C.D == replace with ip address
}
jedis = pool.getResource();

but not able to connect to the remote redis server

Comment: You should provide more information, because I just checked and it works for me.

Comment: ok let me know what else should i provide

Comment: The code, as you have written it, shouldn't compile: "jedis = pool.getResource();" is misplaced.